# adding console.log to the class body causes error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

when i add that `console.log(3);` to the class below it throws error

```
        class AlbumList extends Component {
          state ={ albums: [] };

    console.log(3);

          componentWillMount() {
            console.log(4);
            axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
          .then(response => this.setState({ albums: response.data }));
      }

      renderAlbums() {
        console.log(5);
        return this.state.albums.map(
          album => <AlbumDetail key={album.title} myAlbum={album} />
        );
      }

      render() {
        console.log(6);
        return (
           <View>
              {this.renderAlbums()}
               </View>
            );
          }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: that is not a valid syntax, put that inside any method, check [MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `console.log(3)` inside any method, example you can add it on `componentDidMount()`

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log(3)
}
```

Comment: i know i asked for the reason,

Comment: I think just because there is not the right place to put `console.log`, we just can declare props and method on that place.